# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, graphql, system

When I execute my project and reach this line:

```
Dim response As GraphQLResponse(Of JObject) = graphQLHttpClient.SendQueryAsync(Of JObject)(request).Result
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

File name: 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   en System.Text.Json.PooledByteBufferWriter..ctor(Int32 initialCapacity)
   en System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCoreString(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   en System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[TValue](TValue value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   en GraphQL.Client.Serializer.SystemTextJson.SystemTextJsonSerializer.SerializeToString(GraphQLRequest request) en /_/src/GraphQL.Client.Serializer.SystemTextJson/SystemTextJsonSerializer.cs:línea 37
   en GraphQL.Client.Http.GraphQLHttpRequest.ToHttpRequestMessage(GraphQLHttpClientOptions options, IGraphQLJsonSerializer serializer) en /_/src/GraphQL.Client/GraphQLHttpRequest.cs:línea 32
   en GraphQL.Client.Http.GraphQLHttpClient.<SendHttpRequestAsync>d__34`1.MoveNext() en /_/src/GraphQL.Client/GraphQLHttpClient.cs:línea 116
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   en System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   en GraphQL.Client.Http.GraphQLHttpClient.<SendQueryAsync>d__27`1.MoveNext() en /_/src/GraphQL.Client/GraphQLHttpClient.cs:línea 77
```

The version of the system.buffers.dll file that the project references is 4.0.30 but when I execute I don't know why it runs like the 4.0.2.0 version and the error occurs.
The System.Buffers package installed is the 4.5.1 version.

I've tried a lot of different solutions like opening the .vbproj to see if the reference is actually for the 4.0.3.0, and it's like that, looking the app.config also for the same and with the bindig redirect also from 0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0 to 4.0.3.0, I have been trying to search for any place where the 4.0.2.0 can be referenced but everywhere I look it's the 4.0.3.0 version and the error I don't know where occurs

I expect to reach the information I'm searching for, but for that I need to execute that line and reach the response